# Row aggregation when values are close enough in a column

Tags: r, time, dataset, row, aggregation

I have a dataframe with 2 columns

```
        time     x
  1306247226     5
  1306247236    10
  1306248127    20
  1306248187    36
  1306249248    28
  1306249258    24
  1306249259    20
  ...
```

I'd like to aggregate the rows whose values in the 'time' column are close enough
(eg. let's say their difference is less than 60.) and sum their 'x' values in the aggregated row. The 'time value in the aggregated row will be the one of the first row of the aggregation. ('time' is an unix timestamp)

The goal is to have as output of this example:

```
        time     x
  1306247226    15
  1306248127    20
  1306248187    36
  1306249248    72
  ...
```

The dataset is quite big, a 'for' loop will take a long time... but if it is the only option I can deal with it and wait.
Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this :

First I create a new column for aggregation

```
dat$gg <- cumsum(c(0,diff(dat$time)) > 60)
```

Then I use the `plyr` package to apply function aggregation

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat,.(gg),summarise,time = head(time,1),res = sum(x))
  gg       time res
1  0 1306247226  15
2  1 1306248127  56
3  2 1306249248  72
```

**Edit after comment**

The Op wanted a threshold of 60, not greater than 60. So I need to change the `>` to `>=`

```
dat$gg <- cumsum(c(0,diff(dat$time)) >= 60)

ddply(dat,.(gg),summarise,time = head(time,1),res = sum(x))
  gg       time res
1  0 1306247226  15
2  1 1306248127  20
3  2 1306248187  36
4  3 1306249248  72
```

Comment: They aren't identical because the OP wanted a threshold of 60, not greather than 60. Hence, `>` should be replaced with `>=`.